# Connectivity loss between VMs on VirtualBox until DNS cache is restarted

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I use VirtualBox for a lab environment with VMs running various versions of Windows. One thing that keeps happening and I don't know why (never seen it before on my VMware servers) is that DNS connectivity will be loss between VMs. I can *nslookup* and that works, but *ping* doesn't, and no other app will be able to resolve the other VM. This happens either on bootup, or at random times while the VM is running. The only way to fix it is by:

```
net stop dnscache
net start dnscache
```

Right now I'm thinking it's either something to do with VirtualBox, or the fact that I'm cloning VMs (I do randomize MACs for each new VM). Anyone has seen this before?

Comment: Can you get rid of VirtualBox? That may or may not solve this problem and a whole host of other ones.

Comment: VmWare workstation?

Comment: Another software another set of problems.

Answer (score 0):

I really doubt that VirtualBox is at fault here. You are experiencing problems with one of the services inside a guest operating system.

Only thing VirtualBox can be at fault here are maybe short network outages - but I doubt it. Those kind of bugs would get notice in the community. One of the ideas I have is that your guests fail to get responses and maybe do a negative caching. That means that Windows is caching negative responses. My suggestion would be to lower your negative caching time in:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\DNSCache\Parameters\NegativeCacheTime (DWORD)
```

Try setting it to 0, to disable it completely and see if the issues will occur again. My impression is that somehow you don't get all the answers and negative responses get cached.

To try and debug stuff further, you can use:

```
ipconfig /displaydns
```

at the time of the outage. You can also pipe it to specific name you are trying to resolve, and figure out what is cached:

```
ipconfig /displaydns | findstr mydomain.com
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Everything else I tried didn't work.. flushing DNS, ARP, etc. Only stopping or restarting dnscache service gets rid of the issue. As I said nslookup always returns the right answer, but nothing else will resolve the host. And it always happens for one of the VM, but it's random. Once VM1 won't be able to talk to VM3. The next day VM2 may not be able to talk to VM1, etc.

Comment: If it's related only to DNS records for other VMs, why don't you just hardcode dns names into hosts file?